# Database schema for storing the inventory item slot

Tags: mysql, sql, database, game-development

I am working on a small web project where I would like to have an user inventory like in the RPG games or shooting games. I want to keep it as simple as possible. What I want to achieve is to store the slots of the items so that next time when the page is loaded, items would stay on the correct position.Items will have fixed positions such as, one slot for rifle, one slot for headgear.

What kind of relation and db schema should I create for that? I am using MySQL

I have the following schema so far:

[image: current_db]

Comment: it's the wrong forum here to discuss stuff like that. But in general I would add a configuration table for the slots. Otherwise you would need to model them into the user table which is bad practice from my point of view as every change of the slots would require rework on the table. Then you have a combined key on the user inventory with user_id and slot_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume some items can occupy one of several slots. I'd create a couple of new tables:

```
create table slots (
  id int primary key,
  name varchar(20) -- 'headgear', 'rifle', 'coin pocket'
);

create table inventory_slot (
  item_id int not null,
  slot_id int not null,
  primary key (item_id, slot_id),
  foreign key (item_id) references inventory_item(id),
  foreign key (slot_id) references slots(id)
);
```

There's at least one row in `inventory_slot` for each possible inventory item, and there may be multiple rows in `inventory_slot` for the same item, if it is allowed to be held in multiple places on a given user's inventory.

Then modify the user inventory table:

```
create table user_inventory (
  id int primary key,
  user_id int not null,
  item_id int not null,
  slot_id int not null,
  unique key (user_id, slot_id),
  foreign key (user_id) references user(id),
  foreign key (item_id, slot_id) references inventory_slot(item_id, slot_id)
);
```

This allows only one item per slot per user because of the `unique key`. The items must reference a row in `inventory_slot` so you know they can only be held in slots that have been designated as ok for a given item.